# How to fix overwritePermissions to user not working

Tags: discord.js

I want the bot to change member permissions and set "send messages" to `false` if someone uses `$done @user`.

```js
client.on('message', async message => {
  if (message.author.bot) return;

  if (message.content === prefix + "done") {
    var user = message.guild.member(message.mentions.users.first());

    message.channel.overwritePermissions(user, {
      SEND_MESSAGES: false
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Does the command run? Does the console show any error? Does the bot have the required permission to manage channels?

Comment: the command is running but its not working

Comment: What about the other two questions I asked you?

Comment: the command is running and the console don't showing any errors and the bot have the ``Administrator`` permission

Comment: The way you're using the `overwritePermissions` method seems right. Try using `console.log(user)` to see if the variable is defined.

Comment: i tried using just ``$done`` without mentioning the user and the user logged this:
``Supplied parameter was neither a User nor a Role.``

Comment: i using ``console.log("Working")`` because ``console.log(user)`` do not working

Comment: i tried many times to reslove it but not working

Comment: If `console.log(user)` doesn't work maybe it's because that is the problem: try to use the code from PLASMA chicken's answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should either use:

```js
const user = message.mentions.users.first();
```

or

```js
const user = message.mentions.members.first();
```

and then add a

```js
if(!user) return messsage.channel.send('You need to mention a user!'); below the `const user` line.
```